# How to get all PlayerPrefs keys to make a Drop() function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a problem with Drop function in my game. I need to set all my variables to 0/null, but to make a string to each one separately is very time consuming and costly in the code. Maybe know someone how to get an array of keys in PlayerPrefs?

```
public void Drop()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("AntivirusLevel", 0);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("CPU", 0);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CPUlvl", 0);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("GPU", 0);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("GPUlvl", 0);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("RAM", 0);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HDD", 0);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MB", 0);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level", 0);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LastScore", 0);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Training", null);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
```

Comment: And yes, I don't want to use XML or JSON, want to point out

Comment: You can put those values into dictionary/list and automate the process of setting/getting/cleaning.

Comment: I second @Tatranskymedved solution. For this type of process System.Collection.Generic.Dictionaries is a lifesaver. In my game I have over 100s of resources and when I add,substract,edit,save etc, just call dictionary and do 1 line solution. Also despite you said you don't want XML or JSON, if you are going to planning add more variable to save, PlayerPrefs saving will be hell.

Comment: You should definitely rather consider some external FileIO + encryption e.g. ... PlayerPrefs is read/write able for everyone and I can just go ahead and alter `Level`, `LastScore` etc as I wish. Also an XML or JSON saves you immense time and implementation overhead, avoids any typos, can be changed easily later on for adding/removing fields etc .. don't understand why you explicitly exclude this option ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to get a list of all existing PlayerPrefs in Unity (moreover you also need to each one's type).

There is a plugin that can do that in the editor, maybe you can use it and modify it to work in runtime as well: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/playersprefs-editor-and-utilities-26656

A second alternative would be to manually search the place where the prefs are saved (in windows its in the registery, for example). You can see the location the prefs are saved in each platform here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Last, and this would be my suggestion - you can use [`PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll.html) to delete all player prefs. However, this will delete them and not set a default value like in your code, so you will have to change the code that accesses the player prefs and provide it with a default value.

```
public void Drop()
{
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll(); // Remove all keys so we can get their default values
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}

public int MyGetInt(string prefName) {
    return PlayerPrefs.GetInt(prefName, 0);
}

public float MyGetFloat(string prefName) {
    return PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(prefName, 0f);
}

private void Update() {
    Debug.Log("CPU Value: " + MyGetFloat("CPU")); // When using this instead of directly PlayerPrefs.GetFloat, then it will return 0 if the value doesn't exist, including after Drop() was run
}
```

Note that this will delete ALL your keys in the game. If you only want to reset a certain list of keys, there is no avoiding making a list of it in a JSON file, array, or some other structure. The program can not guess which values you want to reset and which not.